# Devstack installation fails : stack.sh failed Error on exit

Tags: ubuntu, openstack, devstack, openstack-horizon

I'm currently facing a problem while installing Devstack (for an assignement)
During the installation, when running the /stack.sh command on terminal, the following error appears:

stack.sh failed
Error on exit
World dumping... see /opt/stack/logs/worlddump-2022-01-08-133559.txt for details

when opening the .txt file :
'''

```
Compute consoles
================


nova-compute Guru Meditation Report
===================================

Skipping as nova-compute does not appear to be running

neutron-dhcp-agent Guru Meditation Report
=========================================

Skipping as neutron-dhcp-agent does not appear to be running

neutron-l3-agent Guru Meditation Report
=======================================

Skipping as neutron-l3-agent does not appear to be running

neutron-linuxbridge-agent Guru Meditation Report
================================================

Skipping as neutron-linuxbridge-agent does not appear to be running

neutron-metadata-agent Guru Meditation Report
=============================================

Skipping as neutron-metadata-agent does not appear to be running

neutron-openvswitch-agent Guru Meditation Report
================================================

Skipping as neutron-openvswitch-agent does not appear to be running

cinder-volume Guru Meditation Report
====================================

Skipping as cinder-volume does not appear to be running
'''
```

I've tried solutions found on stackoverflow but this error perssists. Please note I'm an absolute newbie when it comes to Ubuntu and devstack ..all I want for now is to access the Dashboard and I'd be pretty happy if I could do at least that.

Thank you for your time.

PS: I have followed all the steps mentionned here : https://computingforgeeks.com/openstack-deployment-on-ubuntu-with-devstack/

Answer (score 0):

post your `devstack/local.conf`
Are you installing in a VM (ubuntu (which one)?) (you probably should as devstack makes a lot of changes)

you can undo changes with `unstack.sh` , then optionally clean.sh , and if really cleaning up:  `rm -rf /opt/stack`  (not normally necessary).

Also recheck networking before rerunning stack.sh   (ip link; ip a, ip route)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).